# Отправить вложение по email из MemoryStream

Tags: c#, email, потоки-данных

Пытаюсь отправить скриншот экрана по email в качестве вложения, предварительно сохранив его в MemoryStream. В результате получаю письмо с вложением, но размер этого вложения равен нулю.

```
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

        Graphics graph = null;

        var bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);

        bmp.Save(memStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

        ...

        Attachment attachData = new Attachment(memStream, "filename.bmp");

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(msgFrom, msgTo, msgSubject, msgBody);

        message.Attachments.Add(attachData);

        client.Send(message);
```

Если же сохранить скрин в файл, а потом этот файл передавать в качестве вложения, то проблем никаких нету.

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, что происходит в данном случае и что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать

```
memStream.Flush();
memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

после `bmp.Save(...)`.

Comment: Таким образом вообще сообщение не отправляется.
если сдвинуть позицию на некоторое число (не на 0), то он передаст это некоторое количество байт. Однако если выставить позицию равную 0, то сообщение вновь не отправляется. Я в замешательстве.

Comment: Хм. Что значит «сообщение не отправляется»? Происходит исключение? Вы случайно не делаете `Dispose` до отправки сообщения?